# Speeding up python image color thresholding/filtering

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am working on a problem where I need to find bounding boxes for white area in an image. Since I am dealing with real-world pictures, I have set a threshold on the RGB values, I create a mask from that and then label it and get bounding box coordinates from that. Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, measure

def bin_labelled_img_to_bboxes(bin_image_labelled):
        bboxes = []
        for j in np.unique(bin_image_labelled):
            if j == 0:
                continue
            curr = (bin_image_labelled == j)
            if np.sum(curr) < 50*50:
                continue
            indices = np.nonzero(curr)
            miny = np.min(indices[0])
            minx = np.min(indices[1])
            maxy = np.max(indices[0])
            maxx = np.max(indices[1])
            bboxes.append(((miny, minx), (maxy, maxx)))
        return bboxes


class WhiteSeperator(object):
    def __init__ (self, img_path):
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.img = io.imread(self.img_path)
        self.bin_image_labelled = np.zeros((self.img.shape[0], self.img.shape[1]))
        self.bboxes = []

    def get_bin_labelled_img(self):
        img = self.img
        chan1 = (img[:,:,0] > 200) * (img[:,:,0] <= 255)
        chan2 = (img[:,:,0] > 180) * (img[:,:,0] <= 255)
        chan3 = (img[:,:,0] > 140) * (img[:,:,0] <= 255)

        bin_img = (chan1*chan2*chan3)
        bin_image_labelled = measure.label(bin_img)

        return bin_image_labelled

    def get_white_bboxes(self):
        final_white_bboxes = []
        self.bin_image_labelled = self.get_bin_labelled_img()
        white_bboxes = bin_labelled_img_to_bboxes(self.bin_image_labelled)

        for bbox in white_bboxes:
            width = bbox[1][1]-bbox[0][1]
            height = bbox[1][0]-bbox[0][0]
            if height > 80 and width > 200:
                self.bboxes.append(bbox)
                final_white_bboxes.append(bbox)
        return final_white_bboxes
```

This takes about 3-11 seconds per image for high res images (3000 something x 2000 something). My assumption is that the variance in time per image depends on the number of white bounding boxes found (blaming the bin_labelled_img_to_bboxes function here)
Since I have to do this on video frames, even 3 seconds is super slow. Can the above be done in a more efficient way?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the a sample image?

Comment: Do you have to use Python, or would you be able to switch to a different language (like C++ or C)? How accurate do you need the results to be? If you can be off by a few pixels (and miss a few isolated white pixels), you could downsample before processing, then convert the bounding boxes back into your original full-frame coordinates. Lastly, if you have access to all the image frames (i.e. you aren't running this live), setting up multithreading to process frames concurrently can speed things up dramatically.

Comment: 1st comment: don't guess, use [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) to see where your code is taking a long time. 2nd: your channel subsetting is incorrect as written (always channel 0?). 3rd: images should be <= 255 by default? So each of those is redundant. 4th: you can use broadcasting: `bin_img = np.all(image > [200, 180, 140], axis=-1)`. This will create fewer temporary arrays. 5th: compare performance of skimage.measure.label and scipy.ndimage.label (not sure which is faster). That's all my low-hanging fruit, I can have another look after you've tried. =)

Comment: I take it back, one more: rather than finding your own bounding boxes, use [scipy.ndimage.find_objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html)